# pass a string value between methods c#

Tags: c#, string, methods, properties

I have a public string I need to use throughout my program.

```
public string connectionString = null;
```

I assign the value as below:

```
internal string accessString()
{
    return connectionString =
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        @"Data Source=" + DBFileName + ";" +
        @"Persist Security Info=False";
}
```

When I run the method the first time the value is correct, however once the execution of the method is complete the value returns to null.

```
internal void selectDB()
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
            choofdlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;
            if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DBFileName = choofdlog.FileName;
                connectionString = accessString();
                Saveproducts();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(connectionString);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }//select db ends
```

The above method gets the value perfectly.

```
internal void writeContents()// read all the text files to the Data base
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(connectionString);
}
}
```

This method above returns null, even though its run after the second method has successfully assigned a value to connectionString.

How can I fix this, I don't want to use static

Comment: Could you please show more code of the class where you use this? When do you call `accessString()` and when do you access `connectionString()`?

Comment: Difficult to know exactly what you've done wrong but likely due to some instance of an object going out of scope - more code needed to confirm, all current answers are speculative (though making `connectionString` static may work but could cause other issues depending on your app)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Session for storing the Connection string or you can use the

```
connectionString as Static variable
```

then it will not reset the value.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change this so that the method creates this value throughout
>   the program

You could do this, `accessString` now always return valid connection string.

```
public string connectionString = null;
accessString();

internal string accessString()
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString)? 
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        @"Data Source=" + DBFileName + ";" +
        @"Persist Security Info=False" : connectionString;
}
```

Comment: you cant use a void and a return in a method as far as I Know

Comment: ahh .. my bad, I overlooked it. thanks @ChongChing correct now.